# Unable to add back localization after i accidentally deleted main.storyboard in xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

my storyboard initially has Chinese(Base), Eng , ZH storyboard file under Main.storyboard. I had accidentally delete the main.storyboard. After that, i tried to recover the main.storyboard by moving the main.storyboard back into Xcode project. The (base) , ENG , ZH storyboard were gone and the localization of app is not working.

Does anyone has idea regarding recover back the localisation ?

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

go open the storyboard file again on the utilities pane

in the file inspector tap choose the language you want to localize to if you can't find this screen you will find a localize button press it the choose base then do the above steps again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Ya5.png)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks you very much, Sherif !  it works and fixed my issue, appreciated for solution!